# css zooming in messes with the divs

Tags: html, css

It took me hours to finally get the format right on all browsers but now the next problem I have met which ive tried working towards but miserably failed is if you try to zoom it messes all the div's up...Here is a screenshot of the normal then the zoomed in out out ones...Is this a hopeless case?
[image: not zoomed]

[image: Zoomed]

[image: Zoomed]

Comment: Please give us a link with the code

Comment: This is just what you'd expect for images/divs styled float:left; How do you want it to look?

Comment: i want it to look like the very first pic but when zoomed shouldnt screw up...

Comment: Where's the link to the code that Andre asked for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to get the images to stay put is to give each its own <td> in a table row. Give the table border-collapse:collapse; and work from there to squeeze the <td>s together.

Comment: i put them in a table and now they all look perfect, thanks :)